# MySQL DAYOFWEEK() in reverse?

Tags: mysql, date, dayofweek

I'm looking for a way in MySQL to convert an integer (0-6) into a day of the week, something like:

```
EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(3) = Wednesday.
```

The [`DAYOFWEEK(date)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function takes a date and gives you a number 0-6 which corresponds to the day of the week (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday), so I'm kind of looking for the reverse of this.

Comment: it's not reverse. first `int f(date)`, second `string f(int)`. `elt(w+1, ...)` makes a job.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Comment: This would be a pretty simple function to write yourself...

Comment: @origamifreak2, what about second part of my comment?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter How would you write it? I'm only somewhat familiar with MySQL, so any hints or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: DAYNAME(date) is what you are looking for? Or you need to be with the Day of Week and not with the date?

Comment: @vp_arth sorry about the confusion. I realized after your comment that my question could be somewhat confusing. as for the second part of your comment, I don't think that would help with my question. Thanks though.

Comment: `I don't think that would help` Why? it's simple as `SELECT elt(weekday+1, 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat')`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html would be a really great place to start.

Comment: @RogerRussel I updated the question to be a bit more clear, hopefully. I'm basically just looking for a way to convert an integer 0-6 into the name of a day of the week (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, etc).

Comment: @vp_arth Ah I see it now, sorry, was busy looking at and responding to other comments. That would definitely work, thanks. I was hoping there would be a native MySQL function I could call, like the example in my question, but from the responses so far, it doesn't seem like there is one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DAYNUMBER;
CREATE FUNCTION DAYNUMBER(s INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
RETURN elt(s+1, 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
```

Test:

```
SELECT DAYNUMBER(1)
```

outputs 'Monday'.

Comment: This is way overkill.  Use native SQL function such as `ELT( n+1 'Sunday','Monday','Tuesday',...)`

Comment: I'm new to SQL so I didn't know that function existed but yeah, that's a much better way to do it. Thanks for bringing that up. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `daynumber(0)` should return `sunday` to be consist with `dayofweek`

Comment: @vp_arth Got it mathmroales and vp_arth (and spencer7593), thanks for the help. I didn't know it was possible to create your own function and I didn't know the elt function existed, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

The `DAYOFWEEK` function should be helpful here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

The only downside is that it expects a date as input, and not a day number. But that should be easily remedied. Just start with an arbitrary date of which you know it falls on a Sunday (like 2016-01-03). Then `ADDDATE` your day number to it. Now you have a date that falls on the same day as your day number, so you can just run that trough the `DAYOFWEEK` function.

```
DAYNAME(ADDDATE("2016-01-03", :day))
```

See for yourself by running the following samples:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(ADDDATE("2016-01-03", "3")) # Wednesday
SELECT DAYNAME(ADDDATE("2016-01-03", "0")) # Sunday
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer also works, and it's shorter. Only small disadvantage is having to use that date in the ADDDATE() function.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that date in there feels a bit wrong to me to. You could wrap it inside a function (like @mathmorales did) to hide it, but still... Tbh this is not something I usually leave up to mySql. I use the database strictly for data storage and querying, and keep all the business logic in my application code. But hey, I as well learned about functions and elt inside mysql today, who knows when it may come in handy ;-)